# Joining on same field, different data type

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, temp-tables

I'm attempting to left join two tables on the same server but different databases using a field titled 'voucher'. The fields contain the exact same data but are stored as different data types. On table a, voucher is stored as a nvarchar and on table b it is stored as a char.

When I run my my query, I am getting a lot of null values for voucher from table b. If I run queries against the tables separately, I can see the values in table b that are coming up as nulls on the joined query.

Any help here would be tremendous.

Comment: Can you add some sample data and desired result?

Comment: A.Acct#              A.VOUCHER B.Acct#             B.Voucher
123456789       UXXXXXXXX          NULL                   NULL
123456789      UXXXXXXXX           NULL                   NULL                                     Above is what I am currently receiving. Would expect that the table b values would fill in with the same data. Here is my join: left join tableB on tableb.voucher = tablea.voucher. As I mentioned before, same data but different data type.

Comment: Please *edit* your question, don't add additional details in a comment section :)

Comment: Also add actual query, sample result and relevant table definition (so we can see data types)

Answer (score 0):

Char type has spaces appended to fill the column length. You need to trim the char field while joining like:

```
left join tableB on rtrim(tableb.voucher) = tablea.voucher
```

Comment: I tried this join but still getting the same results: left join #b on ltrim(rtrim(b.VOUCHER)) = ltrim(rtrim(#a.VOUCHER))

Comment: I tried just the rtrim on table b as suggested above but I am still getting the same amount of nulls.

Comment: Can you try to remove enter characters also? I had such cases before.

Comment: I'm not sure I know how to 'remover enter characters'? Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: like this: replace(rtrim(tableb.voucher), char(13), '')

Answer (score 0):

Those two data types should implicitly convert in most databases. It won't care about the spaces that char adds.

Sometimes the data is not the same even when it looks the same. See the code below for SQL server (I am showing the results sets for those not using SQl Server):

Create the data

```
create table #temp ( id varchar (10))
create table #temp2 (id char(10))
truncate table #temp2
insert into #temp values ('test1')
insert into #temp values ('test' +Char(13))
Insert into #temp2 values ('test1')
insert into #temp2 values ('test')
```

Query #temp

```
select * from #temp
```

Data Returned

```
id
test1
test
```

Query #Temp2

```
select * from #temp2
```

Data Returned

```
id
test1     
test
```

Join Query

```
select t.id as tid , t2.id as t2id from #temp t
left join #temp2 t2 on t.id = t2.id
```

Data Returned

```
tid     t2id
test1   test1     
test    NULL
```

As you can see, if you run this, that adding an unprintable character (in this case a carriage return) makes the values no longer match up in the join. If you have such data in your table then  the values are not the same.  To be more specific as to a fix, I would have to know what database backend you are using.

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management Studio 2012.

Comment: Does that help or do you need more information to suggest a specific fix?

Comment: The question now would be do you need to clean the data itself  (and write a fix to the application to prevent non-printable characters from ever seeping in) or do you need to keep those characters in the table(s) that has them?

Comment: The data would need to stay in the tables as is. I guess I would ask if there is something I can do in my query to work around this??

Comment: Any workaround is going to be a performance killer. But the replace function replacing the bad characters with nothing is your best bet. First you need to find out what they are or else you will have to replace every character from char(1) through Char(32). Another option is a function that replaces them, search the internet there are lots of different examples. But there is no simple fix.